# Google Maps V2 Android Doesnt Appears

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dictionary

I've follow tutorial to create simple android map, here's my source code (MainActivity.java) :

```
package com.tugas.akhir;

import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.CancelableCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.tugas.akhir.R;
import com.tugas.akhir.googlemaps.GMapV2Direction;
import com.tugas.akhir.googlemaps.GetRotueListTask;
import com.tugas.akhir.googlemaps.GMapV2Direction.DirecitonReceivedListener;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

/**
 * 
 * @author Omer F. KAPLAN
 * 
 */
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements OnClickListener, OnInfoWindowClickListener,
        DirecitonReceivedListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Button btnDirection;

    LatLng startPosition;
    String startPositionTitle;
    String startPositionSnippet;

    LatLng destinationPosition;
    String destinationPositionTitle;
    String destinationPositionSnippet;

    ToggleButton tbMode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startPosition = new LatLng(41.036896, 28.985490);
        startPositionTitle = "Taksim Square";
        startPositionSnippet = "Istanbul / Turkey";

        destinationPosition = new LatLng(41.005921, 28.977737);
        destinationPositionTitle = "Sultanahmet Mosque, Istanbul";
        destinationPositionSnippet = "Istanbul / Turkey";

        btnDirection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDirection);
        btnDirection.setOnClickListener(this);

        tbMode = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbMode);

        tbMode.setChecked(true);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
        // map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

    }

    public void clearMap() {
        mMap.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnDirection) {
            clearMap();

            MarkerOptions mDestination = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(destinationPosition)
                    .title(destinationPositionTitle)
                    .snippet(destinationPositionSnippet)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin1));

            MarkerOptions mStart = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(startPosition)
                    .title(startPositionTitle)
                    .snippet(startPositionSnippet)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin2));

            mMap.addMarker(mDestination);
            mMap.addMarker(mStart);

            if (tbMode.isChecked()) {
                new GetRotueListTask(MapActivity.this, startPosition,
                        destinationPosition, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING, this)
                        .execute();
            } else {
                new GetRotueListTask(MapActivity.this, startPosition,
                        destinationPosition, GMapV2Direction.MODE_WALKING, this)
                        .execute();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void OnDirectionListReceived(List<LatLng> mPointList) {
        if (mPointList != null) {
            PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(
                    Color.RED);
            for (int i = 0; i < mPointList.size(); i++) {
                rectLine.add(mPointList.get(i));
            }
            mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);

            CameraPosition mCPFrom = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(startPosition).zoom(15.5f).bearing(0).tilt(25)
                    .build();
            final CameraPosition mCPTo = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(destinationPosition).zoom(15.5f).bearing(0)
                    .tilt(50).build();

            changeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(mCPFrom),
                    new CancelableCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            changeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                    .newCameraPosition(mCPTo),
                                    new CancelableCallback() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onFinish() {

                                            LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                                                    .include(startPosition)
                                                    .include(
                                                            destinationPosition)
                                                    .build();
                                            changeCamera(
                                                    CameraUpdateFactory
                                                            .newLatLngBounds(
                                                                    bounds, 50),
                                                    null, false);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancel() {
                                        }
                                    }, false);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                        }
                    }, true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Change the camera position by moving or animating the camera depending on
     * input parameter.
     */
    private void changeCamera(CameraUpdate update, CancelableCallback callback,
            boolean instant) {

        if (instant) {
            mMap.animateCamera(update, 1, callback);
        } else {
            mMap.animateCamera(update, 4000, callback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker selectedMarker) {

        if (selectedMarker.getTitle().equals(startPositionTitle)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Marker Clicked: " + startPositionTitle,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (selectedMarker.getTitle().equals(destinationPositionTitle)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Marker Clicked: " + destinationPositionTitle,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        selectedMarker.hideInfoWindow();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }
}
```

Beside MainActivity.java, i write down GetRotueListTask.java, here's source code :

```
package com.tugas.akhir.googlemaps;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.tugas.akhir.googlemaps.GMapV2Direction.DirecitonReceivedListener;

public class GetRotueListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final Context mContext;
    GMapV2Direction mGMDirection = new GMapV2Direction();
    LatLng fromPosition;
    LatLng toPosition;
    List<LatLng> mPointList;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private int mDirectionMode;

    DirecitonReceivedListener mListener;

    public GetRotueListTask(Context context, LatLng fromPosition,
            LatLng toPosition, int mDirectionMode,
            DirecitonReceivedListener mListener) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.fromPosition = fromPosition;
        this.toPosition = toPosition;
        this.mDirectionMode = mDirectionMode;
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mGMDirection.setParams(fromPosition, toPosition, mDirectionMode);
        mPointList = mGMDirection.getPointList(this.mContext);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (mPointList != null) {
            mListener.OnDirectionListReceived(mPointList);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this.mContext, "Error downloading direction!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
                .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            // Background: Connected to internet
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            dialog.setMessage("Downloading directions...");
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            this.cancel(true);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Not connected to internet!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }
}
```

After that i according tutorial, i write GMapV2Direction.java :

```
package com.tugas.akhir.googlemaps;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

/**
 * @author KAPLANDROID
 */
public class GMapV2Direction {

    LatLng src, dest;
    public List<LatLng> pointToDraw;

    public static final int MODE_DRIVING = 1;
    public static final int MODE_WALKING = 2;

    public int mDirectionMode;

    public void setParams(LatLng src, LatLng dest, int mMode) {
        this.src = src;
        this.dest = dest;
        this.mDirectionMode = mMode;
    }

    public List<LatLng> getPointList(Context mContext) {
        if (src != null || dest != null) {
            // connect to map web service
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(makeUrl(src, dest));
            HttpResponse response;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = null;

                is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                String line = "0";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                reader.close();
                String result = sb.toString();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray routeArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes
                        .getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
                pointToDraw = decodePoly(encodedString);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return pointToDraw;
        } else {
            throw new NullPointerException(
                    "Source or Destination coordinate is null. You must call \"setParams(LatLng,LatLng)\" method first!");
        }
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String poly) {

        int len = poly.length();
        int index = 0;
        List<LatLng> decoded = new LinkedList<LatLng>();
        int lat = 0;
        int lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b;
            int shift = 0;
            int result = 0;
            do {
                b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            decoded.add(new LatLng((lat / 1E5), (lng / 1E5)));
        }

        return decoded;
    }

    private String makeUrl(LatLng src, LatLng dest) {

        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();

        urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
        // from
        urlString.append("?origin=");
        urlString.append(Double.toString((double) src.latitude));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString((double) src.longitude));
        // to
        urlString.append("&destination=");
        urlString.append(Double.toString((double) dest.latitude));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString((double) dest.longitude));
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&units=metric");

        if (mDirectionMode == MODE_DRIVING) {
            urlString.append("&mode=driving");
        } else if (mDirectionMode == MODE_WALKING) {
            urlString.append("&mode=walking");
        }

        Log.d("Request URL", "URL=" + urlString.toString());
        return urlString.toString();
    }

    public interface DirecitonReceivedListener {
        public void OnDirectionListReceived(List<LatLng> mPointList);
    }
}
```

Then i write a layout like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
         />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tbMode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/map"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnDirection"
            android:textOff="Walking"
            android:textOn="Driving" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDirection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/map"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/map"
            android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
            android:text="@string/getdirection" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, i add some code to AndroidManifest as shown bellow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tugas.akhir"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Requaired Permissions for Google Maps V2 - Start - Kaplandroid -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.tugas.akhir.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.tugas.akhir.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <!-- Requaired Permissions for Google Maps V2 - End - Kaplandroid -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- API KEY for Google Maps V2 - Start - Kaplandroid -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="-------- MY GOOGLE API KEY -------------" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- API KEY for Google Maps V2 - End - Kaplandroid -->

        <activity
            android:name="com.tugas.akhir.MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Later i export it to .apk file, then install it to my device. But,... when i open it, it didnt show any maps, it only show plus & minus button, there is nothing except those button. I've search to internet, it said that my problem is put this code to my AndroidManifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I've put that code, but it still doesnt show any maps, the some article said that the problem is reference to google play library. I've successfull reference my project to google-play-service library, but it's still failed. Anyone can help to fix my problem, please ??? thank you very much

Comment: Any messages in logcat?

Comment: are there any messages like Cannot contact Google servers or so???

Comment: Henry : I'm using android smartphone device so, nothing logcat messages

@Lal : There's no messages, it's  only show plus (+) minus (-) button, the maps doesn't appears

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your sha1 hash of your certificates or packageId you use is incorrectly set up in google api console for your maps. It's important to use proper sha1 hash and right package id. Also note you may also want to add your **debug certificate** as well.

Comment: My android src project folder has 2 package, those are "com.tugas.akhir" and "com.tugas.akhir.googlemaps",.... when i create Google Maps API Key, i only submit "com.tugas.akhir" package, is it affected ??? help please

Answer (score 0):

It may problem with your API key mentioned in your Android Manifest file. Make sure that it was generated with correct SHA-1 key + your package name mentioned in the android manifest file..

And also check whether Google Maps Android API V2 is turned on in Google APIs Console located in services tab.

**Note: After generating new API key uninstall your old app in the device and try again with new installation.**

Comment: i've check some times my SHA1, it was generated by keytool jdk, then i submit to code google to get Google Maps API Key. I've set my Google Maps Android API V2 turned on,.... but my android folder project has 2 package, they are "com.tugas.akhir" and "com.tugas.akhir.googlemaps", but when I submit package & SHA1 to Google Code to get Google Maps API Key, I only submit one of them, it's "com.tugas.akhir",... is it affected ??? help please

Comment: you need to create API key with your package name which is mentioned in the android manifest file but not your android folder project i.e., com.tugas.akhir

Answer (score 0):

You must change APIKEY value with your own APIKEY as mentioned on Manifest file

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="-------- MY GOOGLE API KEY -------------" />
```